# Find all n such that $\phi(n) = n/2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

My idea for the solution is something like this:

Since $2 | n$, $n = 2^a p_1^{e1} p_2^{e2} \cdots p_t^{et}$ where $a \geq 1$.

Then, $n/2 = \phi(2^a) \phi(p_1^{e1}) \phi(p_2^{e2}) \cdots \phi(p_t^{et})$.

Looking at the case that $t = 0$,

$n/2 = \phi(2^a) = 2^{a-1}$, and therefore $n = 2^a$.

Otherwise, $n = 2^a \phi(p_1^{e1}) \phi(p_2^{e2}) \cdots \phi(p_t^{et}) = n = 2^a p_1^{e1} p_2^{e2} \cdots p_t^{et}$. Since $\phi(n) < n$, this is a contradiction, and therefore, the only $n$'s that apply are the powers of 2.

Is this right? Also, we were asked to find $n$ such that $\phi(n) = n/3$. How would I go about that one?

Comment: You can apply similar concepts for the case for $\frac{n}{3}$ to deduce that $n$ must be a product of only powers of $2$ and $3$.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119553/how-to-prove-phin-n-2-iff-n-2k and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128021/if-n-2-phin-then-n-2j

Answer (score 2):

[You know that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) 
$$\frac{\varphi(n)}n
=\prod_{p|n, p\text{ prime}} \left[1-\frac 1p\right]
$$

So for every prime $p_0$ $$\prod_{p|n, p\text{ prime}}\left[1-\frac 1p\right]=\frac 1p_0$$

implies, using unicity of decomposition in irreductible fraction: 
$$\{p|n, p\text{ prime}\}=\{p_0\}$$

Comment: What does "prime nb" mean?

Comment: it means prime number.

Comment: Ah. Usually I just see $p|n,\ p\text{ prime}$.

Comment: yes, I think that $p$ is exclusively for prime numbers when dealing with arithmetics.

Comment: Well yes, it's common to see just $p|n$ with the fact that $p$ is prime left implicit. But when I do see it marked explicitly, I've never seen "nb". I think that is very unusual.

Comment: it was just a bad idea I had :)

Comment: No problem. Here, let me give you a +1 for your answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Use the fact that if $\;n=p_1^{a_1}\cdot p_k^{a_k}\;,\;\;p_i\;$ primes, $\;a_i\in\Bbb N\;$ , then

$$\phi(n)=n\prod_{i=1}^k\left(1-\frac1{p_i}\right)$$

so

$$\frac n2=n\prod_{i=1}^k\left(1-\frac1{p_i}\right)\iff 2\prod_{i=1}^k\left(1-\frac1{p_i}\right)=1\iff\ldots$$

Take it from here...

Answer (score 1):

Without using the product formula.

If $\phi(n)=\frac{n}{2}$, then $n$ must be even (since otherwise $\frac{n}{2}$ is not an integer.)

But if $n=2m$ is even, then $2,4,6,\cdots,2m$ are not relatively prime to $n$. If $p$ is an odd prime divisor of $n$, then the set of numbers relatively prime to $n$ would not include any even number nor $p$, which means that $\phi(n)<\frac{n}{2}$.

So the only prime divisors of $n$ can be $2$.